# How to Use a Regex to Validate the Format of a String

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string that looks something like:

```
first_string = "(white cats || 'dogs) && ($1,000 || $500-$900' || 1,000+)"
```

And I replace each word with the text "replace" by doing:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'[\w$\-+,][\w$\-+,\t ]*[\w$\-+,]|[\w$\-+,],', "replace", first_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

And I get out:

```
new_string = "(replace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace)"
```

This works fine. But I'd like to validate that new_string has a particular format.

For example, is there a way using a regex, to make sure that new_string fits the above general format where:

- There are always sets of parens, separated by an `&&`
- Each paren set contains strings separated by `||`
- Where the number of strings in each paren set and the number of paren sets could vary?

Comment: When I validate using regex I would define the general format of the string and then simply check whether my regex produces any matches on the input string. This assumes I can actually define the required regex, though I am not too sure if it would be possible to define a regex for those given conditions though.

Comment: Just write a parser with pyparsing.

Comment: Well - The classic question - [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I hadn't tried anything - didn't know if it was possible. I suppose I was asking what to try and assumed I needed a regex, my knowledge of which is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your string structure with this pattern:

```
^(?:(?:^|\s*[&|]{2}\s*)\([^|)]+(?:\s*\|\|\s*[^|)]+)*\))*$
```

if `&&` can be inside parenthesis too, you can use:

```
^(?:(?:^|\s*[&|]{2}\s*)\([^&|)]+(?:\s*[&|]{2}\s*[^&|)]+)*\))*$
```

If your replacement pattern is good you don't need to check if the parent and the "child" have the same structure.

*Notice: if you want to allow void parenthesis, replace all the `+` quantifiers by `*`*

Comment: Thanks, this works except in the case that I leave the || out, then it still assesses the string as a match.

Comment: @user1697845: Ok it is corrected, but i suppose that && can be inside parenthesis?

Comment: thanks, yes && could be inside the parenthesis, and I suppose || could be between them as well

Answer (score 0):

Not used regex.

```
def is_valid(s):
    def surrounded_by_parens(s, next_validation):
        s = s.strip()
        return s.startswith('(') and s.endswith(')') and next_validation(s[1:-1])
    def separated_by_bars(s):
        return all(x.strip() == 'replace' for x in s.split('||'))
    return all(surrounded_by_parens(x, separated_by_bars) for x in s.split('&&'))

assert is_valid("(replace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace)")
assert is_valid("(replace || replace)")
assert not is_valid("(replace replace) && (replace || replace || replace)")
assert not is_valid("(replace || replace) (replace || replace || replace)")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible to make regex match any set of configurations or formats you want it to. However some of the strings required to match a set of formats are incredibly long. This one isn't too bad:

```
re.match(r"\( \w+ (\|\| \w+ )*\)( && \( \w+ (\|\| \w+ )*\))*$", new_string)
```

This will match:

```
( replace )
( replace || replace || replace )
( replace || replace ) && ( replace )
( replace || replace ) && ( replace || replace ) && ( replace || replace )
```

Comment: Also matches `(replace||replace) fdafd && (replace ||replace ) && ( replace || replace)`

Comment: Oh whoops! Changed to fix Denomales' observation.

Comment: Doesn't pass the OP sample `(replace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace)`

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will match the described foramt `(replace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace)` where:

- There are always sets of parens, separated by an &&
- Each paren set contains strings separated by ||
- Where the number of strings in each paren set and the number of paren sets could vary?

`^(?:(?:&&|^)\s*\((?:(?:\|\|\s*)?\S+\s*(?=\|\||\)))+\)\s*(?=(?:&&|$)))+`

[image]

Input text:

```
(Areplace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace)
(Breplace || replace) fda && (replace || replace || replace)
(Creplace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace) && (Creplace || replace) 
(whitecats || 'dogs) && ($1,000 || $500-$900' || 1,000+)
```

Matches

```
[0] => (Areplace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace)
[1] => (Creplace || replace) && (replace || replace || replace) && (Creplace || replace) 
[2] => (whitecats || 'dogs) && ($1,000 || $500-$900' || 1,000+)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work. One newbie follow up question: would I use re.match with this?

Comment: good question, I don't know python well enough, however in PHP I used    that chunk of input text and `preg_match_all('/^(?:(?:&&|^)\s*\((?:(?:\|\|\s*)?\S+\s*(?=\|\||\)))+\)\s*(?=(?:&&|$)))+$/im',$sourcestring,$matches);` to give the results portion. If you're only validating a single string then re.match should work, but you'll want to include a `$` at the end of the regex to ensure nothing else is trailing the formatted string.